java API GET with WebFlux
I m building a API with Springboot WebFlux. This method can downlaod file. This is the code:
 public Mono<ServerResponse> downloadAttachment(final ServerRequest request) {
        final var idPercorso = request.queryParam("idPercorso")
                .map(Integer::parseInt).orElse(null);
    }

Mono<ServerResponse> additionalCalcualtions(MapFile mapFile, ServerRequest request){
        return Mono.zip(parseUserInfo(request), request.bodyToMono(ObjectNode.class))
                .flatMap(t -> {
                    //var dto = t.getT2();
                    return silverMountainService(t.getT1()).downloadMappaPercorso(StorageType.parse(mapFile.storageType),mapFile.omniaClass, mapFile.getFileName()
                            )
                            .flatMap(fileResult -> ServerResponse.ok()
                                    .headers(h -> h.setContentDisposition(
                                            Optional.ofNullable(mapFile.getFileName())
                                                    .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                                                    .map(filename -> ContentDisposition.attachment().filename(mapFile.getFileName()).build())
                                                    .orElseGet(() -> ContentDisposition.inline().build() )
                                    ))
                                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(fileResult.getContent()))
                            );
                })
                .onErrorResume(CustomHttpException.class, assEx -> {
                    log.error("Error({}): {}", assEx.getErrorId(), assEx.getMessage());
                    return ServerResponse.status(assEx.getHttpStatus()).bodyValue(String.format("ErrorID: %s", assEx.getErrorId()));
                })
                .onErrorResume(Exception.class, ex -> {
                    var errId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    log.error(String.format("Error(%s) %s", errId, ex.getMessage()), ex);
                    return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).bodyValue(String.format("ErrorID: %s", errId));
                });
    }

To call this method, I m using the following link:
myUrl/downloadMappa?idPercorso=2

Now if I try to call my method with json body like this
{}

my method works correctly. If I try to call my method without json body the return me empty response.
How can I make to change my code to accept NULL as body?

The code posted does not compile. What is the code accepting your call? Also, when you do your request with / without json body, do you also switch from method (POST / GET)?

try using Optional as request body

Please add the implementation of the endpoint myUrl/downloadMappa?idPercorso=2

When you do Mono.zip(parseUserInfo(request), request.bodyToMono(ObjectNode.class)), you do not handle the case when one of both input Monos are empty. If you want to handle null request body or user details, you should do Mono.zip(parseUserInfo(request), request.bodyToMono(ObjectNode.class)).defaultIfEmpty(Tuples.of(null, null))
